# storyboard in xcode11 not working in a old project

Tags: storyboard, xcode10, xcode11

so i've updated to xcode 11 , but the problem is that the storyboard is not loading in the old project that was created with xcode10 ... below is the thing that i'm getting when i press on the storyboard ...

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14490.70" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina5_5" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>`